# More than one variable in php arrays

Tags: php

In a form within a sqlsrv_fetch_array I have

```
<select class="styled-select" name="StockArray['.$row1['ProductID'].']" required><option selected></option><option>0</option><option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option><option>5</option><option>6</option><option>7</option><option>8</option><option>9</option><option>10</option><option>11</option><option>12</option><option>13</option><option>14</option><option>15</option></select>
```

and on the page after submitting that form I have this foreach to construct an insert.

```
$InsertDate = date("Y-m-d H:i:s");

foreach ($_POST['StockArray'] as $ProductID => $Qty) {$InsertList .= "('".$ProductID."', '".$Qty."', '".$InsertDate."', '1'),";}
$InsertList = rtrim($InsertList, ',');
```

What I would like to pass is an extra variable within $_POST['StockArray'] called $row1['LastQty'] so I can add an additional column in my insert. I don't think that is technically possible for an array to have more than just one value per key but I'm here to see if there is a workaround for that for what I'm trying to do.

Comment: `StockArray[<?=$row1['ProductID']?>]` maybe

Comment: @devpro I'm not sure what I'm looking at, I still want product ID in there however I would also like to pass $row1['LastQty'] as well for example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can by encoding/decoding the variables. So, for example if your productID is 4 and you want to encode a LocationID (let say 28) then you can name the variable like this: P4L28, so in php:

```
$sel = '<select class="styled-select" name="' . "P{$row1['ProductID']}L{$row1['LocationID']}" // and so on...
```

Then you will need to look into the $_POST for each combination:

```
foreach ($_POST as $code => $qty) {
    echo "$code => $qty <br>" ;    
}
```

If you just need to output the lastQty in the form then you can just print it as plain HTML, because you won't need it back in the $_POST.

```
<select ...><p>Last quantity: <?php echo $row1['lastQty'] ; ?></p>


    .
```

Comment: Great, I made a few tweaks but that works well for what I wanted thank you, in the form:

    name="StockArray['."{$row1['ProductID']};;{$row1['LastQty']}".']"

and in the resulting for each:

    foreach ($_POST['StockArray'] as $variables => $Qty) {list($ProductID, $LastQty) = explode(";;", $variables); echo $ProductID.'  '.$Qty.'   '.$LastQty.'<br>';}

Comment: Interesting, I didn't think about using explode(), thanks for the feedback.

Comment: No problem, I can't claim it as an orginal thought just the path I found when looking for a way to seperate the values on the other side.